# MongoDB faceted search

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I could have been in a struggle that to derive a facet search in the mongodb with c# driver. I have verified many tutorials but didn't get the suitable solution.
My document/collection will be as follows.

```
db.products.insert([
    {"product_name": "Product 1", "year":2014,"Manufacturer":"manufacturer1"},
    {"product_name": "Product 2",  "year":2015,"Manufacturer":"manufacturer2"},
    {"product_name": "Product 3",  "year":2014,"Manufacturer":"manufacturer1"},
    {"product_name": "Product 4",  "year":2015,"Manufacturer":"manufacturer2"},
    {"product_name": "Product 5",  "year":2014,"Manufacturer":"manufacturer1"}
])
```

I want the output like

Year:

2014 : 3

2015 : 2

Manufacturer

Manufacturer1:3

Manufacturer1:2

Could any one please help me to solve the above problem using c# driver.

Answer (score 0):

Using mongodb shell this can be done using $group in two phases:

```
db.products.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$year",count:{$sum:1}}}])

db.products.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$Manufacturer",count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Comment: I want this to be in a single query using C#, Can it  be done?

Comment: It can't currently be done by any driver because the server doesn't have this support. However, keep track of this ticket, on track for server 3.4: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23654.

Comment: The new c# driver supports this but i can't figure out how to get it to work, to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple pipelines inside a faceted query. But remember that you cannot pass the output of one pipe to another pipe.

> Each sub-pipeline within $facet is passed the exact same set of input documents. These sub-pipelines are completely independent of one another and the document array output by each is stored in separate fields in the output document. **The output of one sub-pipeline can not be used as the input for a different sub-pipeline within the same $facet stage.** If further aggregations are required, add additional stages after $facet and specify the field name, , of the desired sub-pipeline output.

You can try out the following query to get the desired result.

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $facet : {
            year : {
                $group : {
                    _id : '$year',
                    count : {
                        $sum : 1
                    }
                }
            },
            manufacturer : {
                $group : {
                    _id : '$Manufacturer',
                    count : {
                        $sum : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```